# how to return Consumer from Function interface

Tags: java, java-8

I have learning functional interfaces. I have written below code to return a `Consumer` from `Function` interface but it's not working. It's returning output `0`. I don't understand why it returning`0`.

**Code:**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Function<Integer, Integer> factorial = n -> IntStream.rangeClosed(2, n)
            .reduce(1, (x, y) -> x * y);

    Function<Integer, Consumer<Integer>> f3 = n -> {
        return x -> System.out.println(factorial.apply(x * factorial.apply(n)));
    };

    f3.apply(5).accept(2); // output 0
}
```

Can someone explain why this is(`f3.apply(5).accept(2)`) returning `0`. Is there any other way to implement this.

Comment: you do know that you basically try to calculate `(2 * (5!)! = (2 * 120)! = 240! ~ 4 * 10^468`? code works for, e.g. `f3.apply(3).accept(2) = 479001600`.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something specific or just run tests ?

Comment: @azro I'm just learning functional interfaces. so i tried to return `Consumer` from `Function` interface. suggest me any other better approach if you know.

Comment: its because of data type? Integer will not be able to hold the result. Integer going out of range after 16!

Comment: @Turing85 thanks, can you suggest a better way to implement this if possible

Comment: Implement exactly this ? A double factorial ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `Consumer` in a variable, you need to split your code in 2 parts

```
Consumer<Integer> c = f3.apply(2);
//x -> System.out.println(factorial.apply(x * factorial.apply(5)))

c.accept(2);
```

From here you see that something is not gonna be find, as your consumer will do `(x * 5!)!` which is `(120x)!` so with `2` -> `240!`about `10^468`, where an integer can hold only up to `2^32`

---

I'd suggest you remove a level of `factorial` to get easier results to understand

```
Function<Integer, Consumer<Integer>> f3 = n -> x -> {
    System.out.println(x * factorial.apply(n));
};

Consumer<Integer> c = f3.apply(5);

c.accept(1); // 120
c.accept(2); // 240
c.accept(3); // 360
c.accept(4); // 480
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Function<Integer, BigInteger> factorial = n -> {
        BigInteger res = BigInteger.ONE;

        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            res = res.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));

        return res;
    };

    Function<Integer, Consumer<Integer>> f3 = n -> {                // n = 5
        return (Consumer<Integer>)x -> {                            // x = 2
            BigInteger fact = factorial.apply(n);                   // 120 - correct
            fact = fact.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(x));            // 240
            System.out.println(factorial.apply(fact.intValue()));   // too big for int and long
        };
    };

    f3.apply(5).accept(2); // 4067885363647058120493575921486885310172051259182827146069755969081486918925585104009100729728348522923820890245870098659147156051905732563147381599098459244752463027688115705371704628286326621238456543307267608612545168337779669138759451760395968217423617954330737034164596496963986817722252221059768080852489940995605579171999666916004042965293896799800598079985264195119506681577622056215044851618236292136960000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
}
```